# Why are my destructors being called a greater than number of times than expected?

Tags: c++, destructor

I wrote this code to examine behaviour of destructors in c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class WrongDestructor
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    WrongDestructor(int number_) :
    number(number_)
    {}

    ~WrongDestructor() {

    cout<<"Destructor of " <<number<<endl;

//  throw int();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<WrongDestructor> wrongs;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    wrongs.push_back(WrongDestructor(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I found interesting is the output of my program:

```
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 1
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 1
Destructor of 2
Destructor of 3
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 1
Destructor of 2
Destructor of 3
Destructor of 4
Destructor of 5
Destructor of 6
Destructor of 7
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 1
Destructor of 2
Destructor of 3
Destructor of 4
Destructor of 5
Destructor of 6
Destructor of 7
Destructor of 8
Destructor of 9
Destructor of 0
Destructor of 1
Destructor of 2
Destructor of 3
Destructor of 4
Destructor of 5
Destructor of 6
Destructor of 7
Destructor of 8
Destructor of 9
```

It means that much more objects are created than I thought. I expected to have obviously 10 in the collection and maybe next ten created as temporary objects when I fill the collection in the for loop. But there are more of them, some of them are even created more often then the other ones.

Comment: can you rename the title to be a question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `vector` must allocate a larger memory block to hold elements, the new elements are move-constructed into the new, larger memory block. Because your type defines no move constructor or copy constructor, you get the compiler provided default copy constructor instead. The default copy constructor does a simple memberwise copy of all members in the class.

Additionally, inserting the element itself using `push_back` requires moving or copying it in to the `vector`. As a result, you will get copies there too, assuming your compiler doesn't optimize this out. (Note that you can avoid these copies by using `emplace_back`.)

As a result, you are getting several copies of instances inserted into the container early, because when e.g. `1` is copied into a larger memory buffer inside of `vector`, it is destroyed in the old, smaller, buffer.

You can see this behavior more clearly by defining a copy and/or move constructor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class WrongDestructor
{
private:
    int number;
public:
    WrongDestructor(int number_) :
    number(number_)
    {}

    // Copy constructor
    WrongDestructor(WrongDestructor const& copied)
        : number(copied.number)
    {
        cout << "Copied " << this->number << endl;
    }

    ~WrongDestructor() {

    cout<<"Destructor of " <<number<<endl;

//  throw int();
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<WrongDestructor> wrongs;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    wrongs.push_back(WrongDestructor(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program gives the following output: http://ideone.com/S5Zf41

Answer (score 3):

Your vector does not have a predetermined size.  As you are pushing back objects on to the vector, it has to reallocate the vector itself to accommodate the new entries.  This means copying objects over from the memory buffer in to the new one.  Ergo, you see more copies as it does this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::vector::reserve` to allocate enough space for vector. Otherwise, vector need to reallocated continuous space for incoming element which results lots of copies.

```
std::vector<WrongDestructor> wrongs;
wrongs.reserve(10);
```

Comment: Note that the OP will still see a greater than expected number of destructor calls, because the element is copy constructed into the vector.

Comment: yup, I added a little more salt into my answer, coz you guys' answers are very good already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It looks that you add 10 objects into the vector, but in fact 10 more objects created, so 10 more objects would be destroyed at the end.

you should know that when vector's content increase more and more, the vector would increate its capacity of the more objects, what happened during this process?

if vector has no space for the new objects, it would create a larger memory block for more objects, and **copy** the objects it had. Then add the new one (by push_back) , then it would **destroy** the objects and release the orignal memory contented them.

So, when **copy** more objects created, when destroy the original objects, more destructor would be invoked.

The best proctise is  you provide copy-constructor, and printf something in it.
And also prints something in the ctor, you will see the whole process.

More you need to know is the capacity and reserve of vector.